# select p text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, text

I'm retrieving data from mysql like this structure =>

```
echo "<table id='postI" . $chat_row['id'] . "'>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><p class='post_author'>" . $chat_row['user_name'] . "</p><a href='javascript: void(0)' class='edit_post_a'><div class='edit_post'></div></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><p class='posted_on'>" . $chat_row['posted_on'] . "</p></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><br></td>";
echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><p class='posted_msg'>" . $chat_row['message'] . "</p></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

and I can get the table `id` with this expression =>

```
$(".edit_post_a").bind("click",function(){
    var tb_id = $(this).closest("table").attr("id"); //  works , gets the id of the table
    alert($(tb_id + ".posted_msg").text()); // don't work, gets nothing , just alert box 
    });
```

My problem is that want to know text of the third `p`, what I've tried =>

```
alert($("#" +tb_id + ".posted_msg").text());
alert($("#" +tb_id).find("p").last().text());
alert($("#" +tb_id + " p:nth-child(3)").text());
```

nothing works , get empty alert box , I've no idea whats wrong ? how can I fix it ? thanks

HTML code =>

```
<table id='postI245'>
<tr>
    <td><p class='post_author'>USER</p><a href='javascript: void(0)' class='edit_post_a'><div class='edit_post'></div></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p class='posted_on'>DATE</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p class='posted_msg'>MSG</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and so on ...

Comment: Please post your rendered markup instead of the server side codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector selects nothing, you should add `#` for selecting an element by id.

```
var txt = $('#'+tb_id + " .posted_msg").text();
```

or:

```
var txt = $(this).closest("table").find("p:eq(2)").text()
```

Comment: did you tried also ` alert($("#" + tb_id + ".posted_msg").html());` ? note the appearence of "#" and the function `text()` which has been replaced with `html()`

Comment: @Tornike You are welcome, first one doesn't work because you have only one p tag with class of `.posted_msg` http://jsfiddle.net/SPmb6/1/